# Does this function have an inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis

$$f(x)=2^{2x}-2^{x+1}$$

Is this function one-to-one and does it have an inverse in $\Bbb{R}$ ? And if the answer is yes , what is the formula for it ?

I tried many ways like plotting it but I can't find the answer.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint. If you set $z=2^x$ this function becomes $z^2-2z$.

Comment: You probably mean invertible.

Comment: Yes , I mean is invertible function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=f(x)=(2^x)^2-2\cdot2^x\iff(2^x)^2-2\cdot2^x-y=0$

$2^x=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt{4+4y}}2=1\pm\sqrt{1+y}$

$f^{-1}(y)=x=\log_2(1\pm\sqrt{1+y})$

Comment: It seems the function isn't inverse ! Because we have two root for x.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=(2^{2x+1}-2^{x+1})\log2=(2^x-1)2^{x+1}\log2
$$
Is it everywhere positive or negative?

Or, more simply,
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0,\qquad
f(0)=-1,\qquad
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$

Comment: Therefore function isn't one to one and doesn't have inverse. I am right?

Comment: @matinhabi Yes, right so. It is decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok , thanks a lot